# Urban watershed delineation for flash flood events

Tags: watershed, flood

I am currently trying to create urban watersheds using the ending points of flash flood events (in the NOAA Storm Events Database) as outlet points for a city. While doing so, the watershed that is being generated has an unusually small spatial extent (in some cases, just one raster cell). Moreover, the watershed doesn't even contain the beginning point of the event (as in the NOAA Storm Events Database).

For the watershed delineation, I am creating a digital surface model using LiDAR data and following the standard fill, flow direction, and watershed delineation steps in ArcGIS. The purpose of watershed delineation is to find the spatial extent of the event.

Am I following the correct steps to get the spatial extent of a flash flood event? If yes, what am I possibly doing wrong, such that the delineated watershed is so small and doesn't contain both beginning and ending points?